# Generate seeded random int -> int mapping

Tags: javascript, random, mapping

I understand that numeric randomness is typically implemented via an API which looks like:

```
class TypicalRandom {
  constructor(seed) { /* ... */ }
  nextFloat() { /* ... primary source of randomness ... */ }
  nextInt(min, max) { return min + Math.floor(this.nextFloat() * (max - min)); }
}
```

This is useful for producing the same sequence of random floats (or ints, derived from those floats) for the same given `seed`. With such an API, it is not trivial to jump to an `n`th output - for example if we want the millionth value produced by a `new TypicalRandom(seed)` the only way to obtain it is to call `nextFloat` 1,000,000 times.

I am interested in implementing a source of randomness with different capabilities; the API would look like:

```
class Random {
 constructor(size, seed) { /* ... */ }
 nextInt(index) { /* ... */ }
}
```

I don't want `Random` to generate a random sequence of ints. I want it to define a random+deterministic+unique mapping between input `index` to output integers.

Overall:

1. `nextInt` takes an `index` in the range `[0, size)`
2. `nextInt` should return an integer in the range `[0, size)`
3. `nextInt` returns the same value given the same `index`
4. `nextInt` has a unique mapping from `index` -> output values (no 2 indexes produces the same output)
5. `nextInt` should have reasonable performance; crucially, its performance should be independent from the size of `index`
6. the mapping produced by `nextInt` varies based on `seed`
7. `nextInt` should produce a "pretty random" mapping (but not necessarily cryptographically strong)

A [butterfly transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Butterfly_diagram) seems like a promising starting point; its performance is `O(log2(size))` and not dependent on the index; the following code generates some random mappings:

```js
let butterfly = (size, index) => {
  let sizeLog2 = Math.log2(size);
  if (sizeLog2 !== Math.round(sizeLog2)) throw Error(`Non-pow2 size: ${size}`);

  let k1 = index;
  let k2 = 0;
  let k3 = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < sizeLog2; i++) {
    k3 = k1 >> 1;
    k2 = 2 * (k2 - k3) + k1;
    k1 = k3;
  }
  return k2;
};

let butterflySequence = size => {
  // Produces the full random sequence of a given size
  let ret = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < size; i++) ret.push(butterfly(size, i));
  return ret;
};

console.log('Random sequence (size 8): ' + butterflySequence(8).join(', '));
console.log('Random sequence (size 16): ' + butterflySequence(16).join(', '));
console.log('Random sequence (size 32): ' + butterflySequence(32).join(', '));
```

But there are some issues:

- All sequences begin with `0`
- Only naturally works with log2 sizes (`size` must be `2 ** someInt`)
- Unclear how to incorporate `seed`
- These results are really not too random (for example, the 1st half of each sequence is the even numbers, while the 2nd half is the odd numbers)

**Is it possible to meet all 7 requirements above?** And is there vocabulary associated with this problem that could help me research more efficiently? Thanks for any help :)

Comment: Requirement 4 seems like it would be hard to do without this being O(size). The usual way to implement that requirement is to shuffle an array containing 0...size-1.

Comment: Right - there's potential to implement `Random` by underpinning it with an array shuffled by an instance of `TypicalRandom`, and eating `O(size)` memory! But my interest here is the `O(1)` memory approach.

Comment: You'd need a closed-form equation that calculates `random(seed, size, n)` and somehow implements all your requirements. This seems like more of a math problem than coding.

Comment: I think programming questions related to randomness often ride the line between math and software. I'll ask in math forums too.

Comment: It definitely does. But I don't think there can be any O(1) solution other than a mathematical one. But maybe that determination belongs at [cs.se].

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I think it is possible to meet all your requirements using [Linear Congruential Generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator).

It has several parameters, and function would look like

```
var lcg = function(x, a, c, m) {
  next = (a * x + c) % m;
  return next;
};
```

Obviously, your *size* is the same as *m* in the function. Why LCG is applicable is if you carefully select *a* and *c* you could get 1-to-1 mapping from [0...m) interval back to [0...m) interval.

For that LCG parameters must satisfy Hull–Dobell Theorem:

- *m* and *c* are relatively prime
- *a-1* is divisible by all prime factors of *m*
- *a-1* is divisible by 4 if *m* is divisible by 4

Selecting *c* equal to 1 might help with 1.

You could even incorporate seed, as just a shift it the incoming value

```
var lcg = function(x, a, c, m, seed) {
  next = (a * (x+seed) + c) % m;
  return next;
};
```

It is obviously O(1) mapping, quite fast and looks random though not cryptographically strong

Comment: This looks really promising, I'm looking into it and will get back to you, ty!